# Cross browser mixin using Sass

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I'm quite new to Sass so I don't quite know everything about it yet.

My idea is that I create a mixin like so;

```
@mixin crossBrowser($css) {
    -webkit-+$css;
    -moz-+$css;
    -o-+$css;
    $css;
}
```

and then use it by `@include crossBrowser("transition: 0.2s ease-out");`.

I think you can see where I'm trying to go here, is it possible? Or do I have to create a new mixin for every CSS3 property I want to include?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?  [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) already has mixins for just about every property that needs prefixes.  Many mixins have legacy support as well (break-inside, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Solved it like this;

```
@mixin crossBrowser($property, $css) {
    -webkit-#{$property} : $css;
    -moz-#{$property} : $css;
    -o-#{$property} : $css;
    #{$property} : $css;
}
```

Then calling it by `@include crossBrowser(transition, 0.2s ease-out);`

---

**Early 2017 edit**

You should now write your CSS *without* vendor prefixes and then use a tool like https://autoprefixer.github.io to add prefixes.

Comment: This is a really good way to generate properties that you don't need.

Comment: use https://autoprefixer.github.io/ , in this case you will avoid using mixin and unessesery prefixing as a lot of properties doesnt wokr on -o or -ms or -moz et cetera